# Execute specific line of java if in Mac OSX versus Windows

Tags: java, windows, string, macos

I'm running some java code that looks at a file path and searches for the index of the last slash in the path. The issue that I've run into is that the code behaves differently if the user is in Mac OSX versus Windows based on the different slashes used. For example:

```
dir.getPath().lastIndexOf('\\'); //for windows
dir.getPath().lastIndexOf('/'); //for mac
```

Is there a somewhat robust but simple way I can check in the Java code which line is appropriate? I guess I could check for one and see if it returns -1 then use the other (and if that does too then there's an issue with the path) but at this point I'm beyond workarounds and more just curious about how to best handle these sort of issues because I can see it being a common thing. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here's my current workaround:

```
int ind = dir.getPath().lastIndexOf('\\') != -1 ? dir.getPath().lastIndexOf('\\') : dir.getPath().lastIndexOf('/');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `System.getProperty("os.name")` and something like,

```
String osName = System.getProperty("os.name");
if (osName.toLowerCase().contains("mac")) {
  // It's a mac.
} else if (osName.toLowerCase().contains("win")) {
  // It's windows.
} else {
  // Other. Linux, AIX, etc.
}
```

But you really should use [`File.separatorChar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separatorChar) which is *The system-dependent default name-separator character*.

```
int ind = dir.getPath().lastIndexOf(File.separatorChar);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to detect the OS, just use the built-in constant for path characters:

```
dir.getPath().lastIndexOf(File.separatorChar);
```

This property is automatically set to the OS-specific separator character. See [`File#separatorChar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separatorChar).

If you need a `String` instead of a `char`, use `File.separator` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you only care about the path separator then the Java [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class has a mechanism to retrieve the system dependent path separator. So for your case you can just do:
`dir.getPath().lastIndexOf(File.separator);`

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you should be using [`File.separator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) where ever possible

```
String path = dir.getPath();
int lastIndex = path.lastIndexOf(File.separator);
```

But this isn't always an option, in this case, you could convert the separators to a known value...

```
String path = // Some string you've obtained from some where...
path = path.replace("/", File.separator).replace("\\", File.separator);
```

As an indea

Answer (score 1):

File.separator or System.getProperty(“file.separator”) is recommended.
for eg:
you can use `dir.getPath().lastIndexOf(File.separatorChar);` 
or 
   `dir.getPath().lastIndexOf(System.getProperty("file.separator"));` 
to achieve platform independence